# How to display formula field in VF?

Tags: visualforce, outputlink, outputtext

Below is the formula that i have created on Formula text field:

```
if( ISBLANK(Key_Account_Relation__c ),"No Report", HYPERLINK("/00O8E000000P88P?pv0="& Key_Account_Relation__r.AccountGroup__r.Name , "Key Opportunity Report"))
```

I have to display the same formula field on VF page.
I have written below syntax:

```
 <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Key_Opportunity_Report__c}" label="Key Opportunity Report" rendered="{!(Account.Key_Account__c == true)}">
```

Key Opportunity Report

but it is not working as if the relation is blank,it does not display text 'No Report'.
Can someone help me how do I achieve this using VF?

Comment: Why not just output the formula field itself? `{!apex:outPutField value="{!FORMULAFIELD}/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use `apex:outputfield` . It will handle all your configuration.

Eg: if your formula field API name is Test__c then

```
<apex:outputfield value="{!account.Test__c}" />
```

This will show as link or text.

As you want to display it in VF page you can simply do something like

```
<apex:outputlink value="/00O8E000000P88P?pv0={! Key_Account_Relation__r.AccountGroup__r.Name}" rendered="{! Account.Key_Account__c}"> Key Opportunity Report</apex:outputlink>

<apex:outputText value="No Report found" rendered="{! !Account.Key_Account__c}"/>
```

Comment: Problem is I have to remove those formula fields from my objects as I have already crossed 15 object reference limit of my object..

Comment: @DhananjayPatil check my updated answer.

Comment: It display an error message:<apex:pageBlockSectionItem> may have no more than 2 child components 
as I am using pageblock and it has already contained rendered attribute

Comment: @DhananjayPatil put  these both tags in `apex:outputpanel`